# Loop through mini batches of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array that contains 813698 rows:

```
len(df_numpy)
Out[55]: 813698
```

I want to loop through this array using mini batches of 5000.

```
mini_batch = 5000
i = 0
for each batch in df_numpy:
   mysubset = df_numpy[i:mini_batch+i]
   # …
   i = i + mini_batch
```

The problem is that `(len(df_numpy)-1)/mini_batch` is not an integer. So, the last mini batch is not equal to `5000`.

How can I loop though `df_numpy` so that all records of `df_numpy` are included?

Comment: Well what do you want to do with the missing values? Fill with zeros, fill with random values from the original array, or just drop the ones that don't fit in a last batch?

Comment: @NilsWerner: I want to get all mini batches + smaller last mini batch into `mysubset` in the for loop. Then I perform some operations on each `mysubset`.

Comment: Slicing beyond the end of the array is legal in Python and will create the last "smaller mini batch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should get the job done:

```py
mini_batch = 5000
for first in range(0, len(df_numpy), mini_batch):
    mysubset = df_numpy[first:first+mini_batch]
    # ...
```

#### Demo

```py
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df_numpy = np.arange(13)

In [4]: mini_batch = 5

In [5]: for first in range(0, len(df_numpy), mini_batch):
   ...:    mysubset = df_numpy[first:first+mini_batch]
   ...:    print(mysubset)
[0 1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8 9]
[10 11 12]
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case what happens with the last batch that is smaller than `mini_batch`?

Comment: Added a small demo to make it clear what happens with the last mini batch